# Authoritative DNS with forwarding for some domains:

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, internal-dns

I'm setting up a bind DNS server.

Recursion is set to off and I have two zones defined:

```
zone "my_local_private_domain" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/named/zones/my_local_private_domain";
};

zone "2.168.192.in-addr.arpa" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/named/zones/db.2.168.192";
};
```

What I want eventually is for this DNS to forward requests for other zones (for example a DNS resolution to www.google.com) to another server on my local network.

But when I set:

```
forwarders      { 192.168.2.my_other_DNS; };
```

It doesn't resolve:

```
nslookup www.google.com
Server:         192.168.2.193
Address:        192.168.2.193#53

Non-authoritative answer:
*** Can't find www.google.com: No answer
```

Is it possible to define a zone that forwards a requests to another DNS?And if so, how?

Thanks,

Comment: Can you show global options from named.conf file?

Comment: "No answer" indicates that no reply was seen, not even one which indicates an error. You need to fix that problem before proceeding any further. The failure to receive replies could be any number of things, including routing or firewall issues.

Comment: Use dig instead of nslookup for DNS issues. And it is a bad idea to use the same server as authoritative and recursive. Can't you split the two uses?

Comment: @PatrickMevzek My intention is that a second DNS would do the recursion on behalf of this one. I have `forwarders      { 192.168.2.my_other_DNS; };` for this purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See example in page 19 of [BIND v9.11 documentation](https://ftp.isc.org/isc/bind9/cur/9.11/doc/arm/Bv9ARM.pdf): you need to have a `allow-recursion` directive with some ACLs targeted to your internal users.

Comment: So I have to use some sort of a recursion directive to make it work? I am not liking the idea as well...

Comment: As I said in a previous comment: it is always better to separate the authoritative function from the recursive one. With 2 separate servers (or 2 separate daemons on same servers with 2 IPs).